# Unable to display multiple markers using ng-map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

I am trying to use ng-map to display multiple markers dynamically as follows.

```
    <div class="panel-body" style="height:300px">
      <map ng-transclude class='google-map' center='map.center' zoom="map.zoom">
          <marker ng-repeat="pos in tabledata" position="{{pos.lat}}, {{pos.lng}}"></marker>
      </map>
   </div>
```

Controller code is as follows.

```
 $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://xx.xxx.x.xx:3000/abc",
        params:{parameters}
    }).then(function(success){
        $scope.tabledata = success.data;
    },function(error){
        console.log('error ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
```

I am getting error as `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{pos.lat}}, {{pos.lng}}] starting at [{pos.lat}}, {{pos.lng}}].`

Comment: What is success.data? Can you show us console.log(success);

Comment: success.data is  [{"lat":"12.32323","lng":"67.45342"},{"lat":"12.7777777","lng":"56.12335235"},{"lat":"14.3452323","lng":"56.88888"}]

Comment: You can use my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in using angular at,

**`position="{{pos.lat}}, {{pos.lng}}"`** should be **`position="{{[pos.lat, pos.lng]}}"`**

`<marker ng-repeat="pos in tabledata" position="{{pos.lat}}, {{pos.lng}}"></marker>`

This line should be,

`<marker ng-repeat="pos in tabledata" position="{{[pos.lat,pos.lng]}}"></marker>`

So, the code will be,

```
    <div class="panel-body" style="height:300px">
      <map ng-transclude class='google-map' center='map.center' zoom="map.zoom">
          <marker ng-repeat="pos in tabledata" position="{{[pos.lat, pos.lng]}}"></marker>
      </map>
   </div>
```

[**HERE IS AN EXAMPLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/7gbbgdvb/12/)

Comment: But i am getting Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ',' is an unexpected token at column 8 of the expression [pos.lat,pos.lng] starting at [,pos.lng] after making above change.

Comment: try, `<marker ng-repeat="pos in tabledata" position="{{[pos.lat,pos.lng]}}"></marker>`

Comment: This is not working for me I changed marker tag as <marker ng-repeat="pos in tabledata" position="{{[pos.lat,pos.lng]}}"></marker> as suggested. Getting Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{[pos.lat,pos.lng]}}] starting at [{[pos.lat,pos.lng]}}]

Comment: you changed it wrong, `[{{[pos.lat,pos.lng]}}]` should be `{{[pos.lat, pos.lng]}}`it will not be inside array, check the answer and the example demo link which I have given.

Comment: No i did not change it <marker ng-repeat="pos in tabledata" position="{{[pos.lat,pos.lng]}}"></marker> this is what exactly i am using in html page. and in controller function, $http({ method: "GET",
            url: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3000/abc", params:{parameters}}).then(function(success){ $scope.tabledata = success.data; console.log('response ' + JSON.stringify($scope.tabledata) + ' sdata length is ' + $scope.tabledata.length); },function(error){ console.log('error ' + JSON.stringify(error)); }); Can you please tell me whether i can refer tabledata through $scope variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136210/discussion-between-sravan-and-satya-narayana).

Answer (score 0):

Your position data should look like:

```
pos = [40.71, -73.21]
```

So you need convert your data to array definition. Add this function to your controller:

```
$scope.getCoordinates = function(oldPos){
    var newPos : [oldPos.lat,oldPos.lng];
    return newPos;
}
```

And use it in position:

```
<marker ng-repeat="pos in tabledata" position="getCoordinates(pos)"></marker>
```

Comment: I used this.getCoordinates = function(oldPos) {return [oldPos.lat, oldPos.lng];} in controller function and changed marker tag as <marker ng-repeat="pos in tabledata" position="ctrl.getCoordinates(pos)"></marker>. I am getting Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":["12.32323","67.45342"],"oldVal":["12.32323","67.45342"]}....

Comment: @SatyaNarayana in controller turn string to float

Comment: Same issue is repeating. Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":[12.32323,67.45342],"oldVal":[12.32323,67.45342]}